# How to create stored procedure using Azure Data Factory pipeline?

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

How do I create stored procedures using Azure Data Factory pipeline?

What activity should I use?

I have an existing pipeline where a stored procedure will be called and and export its data returned to Azure Storage. But the stored procedure I used is manually created.

Now I wanted to include in the pipeline where it will create the stored procedure first rather than creating it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `copy data` activity **sink** to create a **Stored Procedure**.

In **pre-copy script** under the sink settings, write your script to create a procedure.

> Note: You don’t have an option to write pre-copy script in the source

Below is how I have done this:

1. Create an empty table (dummy) to use as source/sink in copy activity dataset, as we just want to create a stored procedure through this activity.

[image]

2. Optional: Create a variable at the pipeline to write your script

sample code:  `CREATE PROCEDURE p1  AS  select 'Hello' as col1`

[image]

3. Use the variable to execute in the pre-copy script

[image]

4. Stored procedure generated in Azure SQL database successful.

[image]

5. Now to can call the stored procedure in another copy activity or a new pipeline as per your requirement to copy data to Azure storage.

Copy data activity2:

**Source**:

[image]

**Sink**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: In the copy data 1, what did you put in the Source?

Comment: I am using dummy table for source and sink

Comment: Thank you, it works for me. But do you have any other idea without using a dummy table?

Comment: I tried multiple options but didn't work and ended up using a dummy table. As we have pre-copy script only in copy activity and we can't leave the dataset empty I used a dummy table. You can call the Store procedure in the sink if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you're trying to create a stored procedure before you call it in a pipeline Copy Job?

You can use a Pre-copy script to create the Stored Procedure, and if the copy job is targeting that stored procedure, just use the 'Edit' feature and manually enter the name of the procedure.

Comment: No, the creating of stored procedure must be inside the pipeline. And use it as a target.